# Woocommerce different categories sum to bulk prices

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, orders, bulk

When I arrive to the cart I want to count the total articles of different Ids and if they are in both of them in different ranges apply a tier table for them.

For example:

1. List of IDs A: ID1, ID2, ID3 ------->

- Price 1 - 99 | 0.20
- Price 100 - 199 | 0.18
- Price 200 - to the end | 0.14

2. List of IDs B: ID4, ID5, ID6 ------->

- Price 1 - 99 | 0.30
- Price 100 - 199 | 0.28
- Price 200 - to the end | 0.20

If I found from both list A and B 50 they will have the price of the second range.

---

My first approach has been:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_before_cart', 'check_category_in_cart');

function check_category_in_cart() {
    // Set here your product ID (or variation ID)
$total = 0;
$array_ids = array();   
$targeted_id = 351;
$lista = array(351,916,825,528,527,524,192,190,188,186,184,182,180,178,70,68,68,66,64);
// Get quantities for each item in cart (array of product id / quantity pairs)
$quantities = WC()->cart->get_cart_item_quantities(); 
for ($x=0;$x<count($lista); $x++) { 
// Displaying the quantity if targeted product is in cart
    if( isset($quantities[$lista[$x]]) && $quantities[$lista[$x]] > 0 ) {
     $total += $quantities[$lista[$x]];
     array_push($array_ids,$lista[$x]); 
    }

}
    //If is between totals I want to change the price 
        if($total >= 0 || $total < 150 ){
        
         wc_print_notice($total, 'notice' );
            //print_r($array_ids);
    }else if($total >= 150 || $total < 300  ){
        
         wc_print_notice($total, 'notice' );
            //print_r($array_ids);
    }else{
        
        wc_print_notice($total.$array_ids, 'notice' );
            //print_r($array_ids);
    }
    
    foreach ( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $cart_item ) {
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $price = $product->get_regular_price();
       // $cart_item['data']->set_regular_price( 10 );
        //$cart_item['data']->set_price( 10 );
        //print_r($product_id) ;
    
    
 
    }
    

}
```

I reach to get the total quantity of all of the ids, but when I try to change the price it only changes the sale price, and If I left this code working It doesn't allow to finish the orders in the cart .

---

My second approach has been:

```php
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'set_cart_item_sale_price', 20, 1 );
function set_cart_item_sale_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Iterate through each cart item
    foreach( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ) {
        $price = $cart_item['data']->get_sale_price(); // get sale price
        $cart_item['data']->set_price( 5 ); // Set the sale price

    }
}
```

And I found that the prices that are changing are only the sales not the real ones could be for a plugin?

[How is seen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luiyM.png) 
Kind regards

Comment: Hi, I have tried to clarify your question, but it is (still) not completely clear to me yet. **1)** What you mean with _"and if they are in both of them in different ranges apply a tier table for them."_ **2)** Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) **3)** Avoid adding information to your question that is not really important for an answer to your question. For instance: _"usually I work in joomla"_. 
This way the focus on your question is quickly lost. Regards

Comment: Sorry, English is not my mother tongue, later I will try to clarify it all.

Comment: @7uc1f3r my main problem right now is that I only can change the price of the sale as in the attached image but not the main price, I think that if I can solve this the next is possible for my self

Comment: Know that there are many related (or even duplicate) questions and answers to be found anyway. For instance: [Cart bulk quantity discount for specific product tag IDs in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67802148/11987538) or other https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=user%3a11987538%20woocommerce_before_calculate_totals. 
If you merge existing answers, you should be able to arrive at a solution. Regards

Comment: I had checked your reply but even I tried to change only the price how it works it happens as the attached image where only change the sales prices.
Not sure if its because Im using a plugin for bulk discounts or becasuse not using the right hook.

Thanks for your help @7uc1f3r

Comment: I tried to unable the WooCommerce Dynamic Pricing & Discounts plugin and now the prices changes correctly, there is any way to make this plugin load before in this page or not to interrupt this one.

Thanks for your help @7uc1f3r